# How to pass a class object from Scala to Java?

Tags: java, scala, interop

I'm trying to use a Java class library from Scala code.  (JGraphT, to be precise.)  One of the constructors I need to call is

```
public class SimpleGraph<V, E>
    extends AbstractBaseGraph<V, E>
    implements UndirectedGraph<V, E>
{
  public SimpleGraph(Class<? extends E> edgeClass) {...}
}
```

To call this from Java, I would say:

```
UndirectedGraph<String, DefaultEdge> g = new SimpleGraph<String, DefaultEdge>(DefaultEdge.class);
```

What's the correct Scala equivalent?

More specifically, how do I pass the DefaultEdge.class argument to the constructor?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The equivalent Scala code is, as you say

```
val g: UndirectedGraph[String, DefaultEdge] = new SimpleGraph[String, DefaultEdge](classOf[DefaultEdge])
```

But that can DRYed up a bit because Scala can infer the type parameters of your constructor

```
val g: UndirectedGraph[String, DefaultEdge] = new SimpleGraph(classOf[DefaultEdge])
```

But that's not as DRY as it can get.  The "DefaultEdge" type gets mentioned twice.  You can get even more DRY with manifests. First you create a factory for creating SimpleGraphs.

```
object SimpleGraph {
  import scala.reflect.Manifest
  def apply[T, E]()(implicit mfst : Manifest[E]) = new SimpleGraph[T,E](mfst.erasure.asInstanceOf[Class[_ <: E]])
}
```

And with this we can create a graph with either

```
val g = SimpleGraph[String, DefaultEdge]()
```

or

```
val g: UndirectedGraph[String, DefaultEdge] = SimpleGraph()
```

Obviously this technique is only worth it if you create a bunch of SimpleGraphs

Now some caveats and warnings.  Manifests are still considered experimental.  I suspect they're too useful to ever be dropped, but there are no guarantees.  For more about manifests see http://scala-blogs.org/2008/10/manifests-reified-types.html

Answer (score 9):

I found my own answer.  The equivalent is

```
val g = new SimpleGraph[String, DefaultEdge](classOf[DefaultEdge])
```